# How do I make a shell script start at boot in OSX through command line only?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, mining

So I have a very brief `.sh` script in OSX designed to start the system mining at boot (not login!).

```
#! /bin/sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/"
CMD=$DIR"m-minerd -o url -u user:worker -p pass"
$CMD
```

I know this works from executing it as a trial, but I can't figure out how, on an OSX machine (I have root access) to get it to run at system boot. I know launchd is a thing, but it's a GUI (as far as I can tell) and I need the method to be executable on the command line via another shell script that will install dependencies, move everything into place, and place this `.sh` into the folder it needs to be in in order to launch on boot. Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html and `man launchd.plist`

Comment: If this is your actual code, you first need to fix your shebang.

Comment: Not actual code it's just so y'all get the gist. Thanks jtbandes!